# Django Rest Framework - how to combine my two serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models one of which contains text and the other an image and are connected via a ForeignKey. The problem revolves around the `pictures` attribute in my `FortuneSerializer`. In order to `create` I have to uncomment one and comment out another. And, in order to display the results correctly I have to do the same (uncomment/comment out). I can successfully use the modified `create` method in the `FortuneSerializer` but displaying the `pictures` results is a problem.

When I use the `PictureSerializer` inside of the `FortuneSerializer` results are displayed correctly like so:

```
    {
        "id": 16,
        "content": "win the lottery",
        "pictures": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image": "/media/2016/03/09/mypicture.png"
            }
        ]
    },
```

but while they display properly I can't use the `create` to capture the picture. Because of this I comment out `PictureSerializer` in the `FortuneSerializer` and uncomment `serializer.ImageField()` which will successfully create a Fortune instance and capture the picture, but the results don't display the picture url like so:

```
    {
        "id": 16,
        "content": "win the lottery",
        "pictures": null
    },
```

Serializers:

```
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ('id', 'image')

class FortuneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # If uncommented, will display picture url in results, but can't create
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True)

    # If uncommented, will create Fortune with attached Picture,
    # but will display `null` in results
    pictures = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Fortune
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'pictures')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pictures = validated_data.pop('pictures')
        fortune = Fortune.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
        if pictures:
            p=Picture(fortune=fortune)
            p.image.save(str(pictures), pictures)
        return fortune
```

Models:

```
class Fortune(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='fortunes')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Picture(models.Model):
    fortune = models.ForeignKey(Fortune, related_name='pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Views:

```
class FortuneList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Fortune.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FortuneSerializer

def list(self, request, user_id):
    queryset = Fortune.objects.filter(user__id=user_id)
    serializer = FortuneSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any solutions?

**==== UPDATE 1 =====**

I updated the `FortuneSerializer` and `PictureSerializer` as **@YPCrumble** suggested:

```
class FortuneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Fortune
        fields = ('id', 'content', 'pictures')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pictures = validated_data.pop('pictures')
        fortune = Fortune.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)

        if pictures:            
            [Picture(fortune=fortune, image=picture) for picture in pictures]

        return fortune

class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = FortuneSerializer
```

I can create a new `fortune` using the DRF default HTML post form. The form contains a text input for the title and a multiple select menu to select existing picture files (created using the previous serializers, which has a multi file select input). I can select single or multiple files and create the `fortune` with no problems and the picture files now associated with the new `fortune` will be listed. However, I'd like to POST new images with `fortune`. There is no file input in the form for me to select new pictures to upload. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the `many=True` flag for your serializer, you also have to [create multiple objects in the serializer's `create` method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create).

Something like the following could be adapted depending on how your `save` function actually looks:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    pictures = validated_data.pop('pictures')
    fortune = Fortune.objects.create(user=self.context['request'].user, **validated_data)
    if pictures:            
        [Picture(fortune=fortune, image=picture) for picture in pictures]

    return fortune
```